# how to change the color of an arrow

Tags: gnuplot

It seems that this command can not change the color of an arrow

```
set arrow from 22,1590 to 523,1090 lw 3   back  lc rgb "blue" filled
```

But I get

```
duplicated arguments in style specification
```

and it points to the beginning of `filled`.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the order of arguments doesn't matter in gnuplot, unfortunately in your case it does. Use

```
set arrow from 22,1590 to 523,1090 filled back lw 3 lc rgb "blue"
```